# Java wrapper - QUEUELIST_NEED_NATURAL_NEXT

Tags: java, deezer

I am trying to build a Java wrapper around the native SDK and I am rewriting NanoPlayer. I think I managed to get the same flow of events as the native version, but when I play a song, I get a QUEUELIST_NEED_NATURAL_NEXT instead of MEDIASTREAM_DATA_READY. You can see the output below.
What could cause this? And what am I supposed to do on such event?

Thanks a lot in advance.
Stefano

> 34511:327803 dz_crash_handler: [dz_crash_handler_init:286] Crash
>   Handler available Device ID: e91f2fce333d4a7ab9b75cfaee3115e4
>
> ###  MENU
>
> - Please press key for comands:  -   P : PLAY / PAUSE   S : START/STOP   + : NEXT
>
>   - : PREVIOUS   R : NEXT REPEAT MODE   ? : TOGGLE SHUFFLE MODE   Q : QUIT   [1-4] : LOAD CONTENT [1-4]
>
> #
>
> OnConnectCallback
>   (native@0x7f1d843271e0,native@0x7f1d200f2a60,native@0x7f1d842c95c0)(App:native@0x7f1d842c95c0:1)
>   ++++ CONNECT_EVENT ++++ USER_OFFLINE_AVAILABLE OnConnectCallback (native@0x7f1d843271e0,native@0x7f1d200eee50,native@0x7f1d842c95c0)(App:native@0x7f1d842c95c0:4)
>   ++++ CONNECT_EVENT ++++ USER_LOGIN_OK LOAD => dzmedia:///track/136332242 (App:native@0x7f1d842c95c0:2) ====
>   PLAYER_EVENT ==== QUEUELIST_LOADED for idx: 0 Entity: line 1: parser
>   error : Document is empty sas_noad = true; ^ S PLAY track n° 0 of =>
>   dzmedia:///track/136332242
>
> PLAY track n° 0 of => dzmedia:///track/136332242
>
> (App:native@0x7f1d842c95c0:7) ==== PLAYER_EVENT ====
>   QUEUELIST_TRACK_SELECTED for idx: 0 - is_preview:false
>     canPauseUnpause: true, canSeek: true, numSkipAllowed: 1     now:{...}
>   (App:native@0x7f1d842c95c0:8) ==== PLAYER_EVENT ====
>   QUEUELIST_NEED_NATURAL_NEXT for idx: 0 (App:native@0x7f1d842c95c0:11)
>   ==== PLAYER_EVENT ==== UNKNOWN or default

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue: I provided in the config object a wrong cache path value - it must be a directory (existing) while I was setting a file (although existing).

Advise for the beginners: to see some more log, do not call dz_connect_debug_log_disable().

Hope this helps
Stefano